# Loop for adding value to last n values in list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list where I would like to +1 to all the values after *n* in a loop, where *n* is a row index. I want to repeat this multiple times to achieve the following:

```
original_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
multiples = [3,6] #i.e. index 2 & 5

for i in multiples:
    Do Something to +1...

final_list = [1,2,4,5,6,8,9]
```

Slicing lists within loops doesn't seem that clear to me, does anyone know how to think about solving this?

Comment: I think your example is wrong, unless you are counting your first item in a list as 1 and not as 0 (which is the common practice).

Comment: So does the 3 in `multiples` mean the 3rd item (i.e. index 2) or the first occurrence of the number 3 in the list?

Answer (score 2):

```
original_list = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
multiples = np.array([3,6])

cs = np.zeros_like(original_list)
multiples = np.array(multiples) - 1 # since you are not using 0-index
cs[multiples] = 1
original_list + cs.cumsum()
```

Output:

```
array([1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any fancy list slicing actually. You can accomplish this with an additional index, `j`, that goes from `i + 1` (*after n*) to the `len` of the `original_list`.

```
original_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
multiples = [3,6]

for i in multiples:
    for j in range(i+1, len(original_list)): # i+1 if you count from 0, i-1 if you count from 1
        original_list[j] += 1

>>> original_list
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8] or [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9] (with i-1)
```

If you are counting from 1 (instead of 0), then change `i+1` to `i-1` and your `original_list` becomes `[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]`.

Comment: This looks like it will lead to an cartesian explosion, the longer the lists are.

Comment: If the lists are really big, then `numpy` becomes the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

```
original_list = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
final_list = np.array(original_list, copy=True)
multiples = [3,6]

for i in multiples:
    final_list[i-1:] = final_list[i-1:] + 1
```

When wanting the following output

```
 final_list = [1,2,4,5,6,8,9]
```

Comment: Is there a special reason for np.copy()? You could jut use .copy() at the end.

Comment: @Andreas it was a typo, I wanted to write np.array